# Non-Standard Evaluation and Character Vectors

Tags: r, dplyr

Imagine I have a dataset as follows

```
d <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10], c = sample(10))
```

Imagine that I also have a character vector containing variable names

```
v <- c("a", "b")
```

Using `dplyr` I would like to use `v` to `select` variables `a` & `b`.

This will not work,

```
d %>%
  select(v)
```

This is because the `dplyr` packages uses non standard evaluation and expects actual variable names to be passed rather then characters.

Comment: Yes? That's why it has the standard eval version `select_`. Here, `d %>% select_(v)` runs fine.

Comment: Oops, you're both right. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: As usual, you guys are great.  The `_` suffix is super helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For standard evaluation, you will want to use the functions with an underscore after their given name.  In this case that is `select_()`.  And we will also need to use the `.dots` argument to insert your vector into the call.

```
d %>% select_(.dots = v)
```

See `help(select)` and `vignette("nse")` for more.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
d %>% select(one_of(v))
```