# Non-standard evaluation and quasiquotation in dplyr() not working as (naively) expected

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval, non-standard-evaluation, quasiquotes

I am trying to search a database and then label the ouput with a name derived from the original search, `"derived_name"` in the reproducible example below. I am using a `dplyr` pipe `%>%`, and I am having trouble with quasiquotation and/or non-standard evaluation. Specifically, using `count_colname`, a character object derived from `"derived_name"`, in the final `top_n()` function fails to subset the dataframe.

```
search_name <- "derived_name"
set.seed(1)
letrs <- letters[rnorm(52, 13.5, 5)]
letrs_count.df <- letrs %>%
    table() %>%
    as.data.frame()
count_colname <- paste0(search_name, "_letr_count")
colnames(letrs_count.df) <- c("letr", count_colname)
letrs_top.df <- letrs_count.df %>%
    top_n(5, count_colname)
identical(letrs_top.df, letrs_count.df)
# [1] TRUE
```

Based on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955905/using-pre-existing-character-vectors-in-quasiquotation-of-an-expression-with-rla) I thought the code above would work. And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800159/non-standard-evaluation-and-character-vectors) lead me to try `top_n_()`, which does not seem to exist.

I am studying `vignette("programming")` which is a little over my head. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882794/non-standard-eval-in-dplyrmutate) led me to try the `!! sym()` syntax, which works, but I have no idea why! Help understanding why the below code works would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
colnames(letrs_count.df) <- c("letr", count_colname)
letrs_top.df <- letrs_count.df %>%
    top_n(5, (!! sym(count_colname)))
letrs_top.df
#   letr derived_name_letr_count
# 1    l                       5
# 2    m                       6
# 3    o                       7
# 4    p                       5
# 5    q                       6
```

Additional confusing examples based on @lionel and @Tung's questions and comments below. What is confusing me here is that the help fils say that `sym()` "take strings as input and turn them into symbols" and `!!` "unquotes its argument". However, in the examples below, `sym(count_colname)` appears to unquote to `derived_name_letr_count`. I do not understand why the `!!` is needed in `!! sym(count_colname)`, since `sym(count_colname)` and `qq_show(!! sym(count_colname))` give the same value.

```
count_colname
# [1] "derived_name_letr_count"
sym(count_colname)
# derived_name_letr_count
qq_show(count_colname)
# count_colname
qq_show(sym(count_colname))
# sym(count_colname)
qq_show(!! sym(count_colname))
# derived_name_letr_count
qq_show(!! count_colname)
# "derived_name_letr_count"
```

Comment: [`dplyr` automatically quotes its inputs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). Here is the source code of [`top_n`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/top-n.R): it uses `enquo` & `!!` to quote and unquote the inputs as well. Run `qq_show(!!quo(sym(count_colname)))` to see why you need to unquote `sym(count_colname)` with `!!` first before supplying to `top_n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've realized that what I was struggling with in this question (and many other probelms) is not really quasiquotation and/or non-standard evaluation, but rather [converting character strings into object names](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-May/021823.html). Here is my new solution:

```
letrs_top.df <- letrs_count.df %>%
    top_n(5, get(count_colname))
```

Answer (score 6):

According to `top_n` documentation (`?top_n`), it doesn't support `character`/`string` input thus the 1st example didn't work. In your 2nd example, `rlang::sym` converted the string to a variable name then `!!` unquoted it so that it could be evaluated inside `top_n`. Note: [`top_n`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/top-n.R) and other [`dplyr` verbs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) automatically quote their inputs.

Using `rlang::qq_show` as suggested by @lionel, we can see it doesn't work because there is no `count_colname` column in `letrs_count.df`

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
letrs <- letters[rnorm(52, 13.5, 5)]
letrs_count.df <- letrs %>%
  table() %>%
  as.data.frame()

search_name <- "derived_name"
count_colname <- paste0(search_name, "_letr_count")
colnames(letrs_count.df) <- c("letr", count_colname)
letrs_count.df
#>    letr derived_name_letr_count
#> 1     b                       1
#> 2     c                       1
#> 3     f                       2
...

rlang::qq_show(top_n(letrs_count.df, 5, count_colname))
#> top_n(letrs_count.df, 5, count_colname)
```

`sym` & `!!` create the right column name existing in `letrs_count.df`

```
rlang::qq_show(top_n(letrs_count.df, 5, !! sym(count_colname)))
#> top_n(letrs_count.df, 5, derived_name_letr_count)

letrs_count.df %>%
  top_n(5, !! sym(count_colname))
#>   letr derived_name_letr_count
#> 1    l                       5
#> 2    m                       6
#> 3    o                       7
#> 4    p                       5
#> 5    q                       6
```

`top_n(x, n, wt)`

Arguments:

- `x`: a `tbl()` to filter
- `n`: number of rows to return. If `x` is grouped, this is the number of rows per group. Will include more than `n` rows if there are ties. If `n` is positive, selects the top `n` rows. If negative, selects the bottom `n` rows.
- `wt`: (Optional). The variable to use for ordering. If not specified, defaults to the last variable in the `tbl`. 
  This argument is automatically quoted and later evaluated in the context of the data frame. It supports unquoting. See `vignette("programming")` for an introduction to these concepts.

See also these answers: [1st](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50012121/786542), [2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470372/786542), [3rd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49702437/786542)

Comment: thank you. The [3rd post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700912/why-is-enquo-preferable-to-substitute-eval/49702437#49702437) you referenced made me think this would work `x <- enquo(count_coln); laut.top.df <- laut.count.df %>%     top_n(max(10, ceiling(percent * nrow(.) / 100)), !! x)` but it does not. This is definitely the most frustrating concept I've encountered.

Comment: @Josh: what is `count_coln`? `enquo` is usually used inside a function. I suggest you watch [Hadley's 5min tidy evaluation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nERXS3ssntw)

Comment: thanks, I wondered if that was the issue with `enquo`. Still trying to wrap my head around what `sym` does. `count_colname` represents what I want the column name to be. It consists of a unique identifier derived from my original database search (`"derived_name"` in the example) and `"_letr_count"` I make it here `count_colname <- paste0(search_name, "_letr_count")` and use it here `colnames(letrs_count.df) <- c("letr", count_colname)` and in the `top_n` function that is causing my struggle.

Comment: `sym()` transforms a string into a variable name. I suggest you use `rlang::qq_show()` to experiment with unquoting and see the results. For instance try `var <- "cyl"; rlang::qq_show(mutate(data, !!var + 1))`. Then try with `!!sym(var)`

Comment: @Josh: This link might help ease your pain going into tidyeval https://colinfay.me/tidyeval-1/