# Create R function using dplyr::filter problem

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I've looked at other answers but cannot find a solution for the code below to work. Basically, I'm creating a function that `inner_join` the two data frame and `filter` based on a column inputted in the function.

The problem is that the `filter` part of the function doesn't work. However it works if I take filter off the function and append it like `mydiff("a") %>% filter(a.x != a.y)`

Any suggestion is helpful.

Note that I am *function input* in quotes

```r
library(dplyr)

# fake data
df1<- tibble(id = seq(4,19,2), 
             a = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"), 
             b = c(rep("foo",3), rep("bar",5)))
df2<- tibble(id = seq(10, 20, 1), 
             a = c("d","a", "e","f","k","m","g","i","h", "a", "b"),
             b = c(rep("bar", 7), rep("foo",4)))

# What I am trying to do
dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2, by = "id") %>% select(id, b.x, b.y) %>% filter(b.x!=b.y)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      id b.x   b.y  
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1    18 bar   foo

# creating a function so that I can filter by difference in column if I have more columns
mydiff <- function(filteron, df_1 = df1, df_2 = df2){
  require(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
  col_1 = paste0(quo_name(filteron), "x")
  col_2 = paste0(quo_name(filteron), "y")
  my_df<- inner_join(df_1, df_2, by = "id", suffix = c("x", "y"))
  my_df %>% select(id, col_1, col_2) %>% filter(col_1 != col_2)
}

# the filter part is not working as expected. 
# There is no difference whether i pipe filter or leave it out
mydiff("a")

#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>      id ax    ay   
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1    10 d     d    
#> 2    12 e     e    
#> 3    14 f     k    
#> 4    16 g     g    
#> 5    18 h     h
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it did not work in your original function was that `col_1` was `string` but `dplyr::filter()` expected "unquoted" input variable for the LHS. Thus, you need to first convert `col_1` to variable using `sym()` then unquote it inside `filter` using `!!` (bang bang).

`rlang` has really nice function `qq_show` to show what actually happens with quoting/unquoting (see the output below)

See also this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51738267/)

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

# creating a function that can take either string or symbol as input
mydiff <- function(filteron, df_1 = df1, df_2 = df2) {

  col_1 <- paste0(quo_name(enquo(filteron)), "x")
  col_2 <- paste0(quo_name(enquo(filteron)), "y")

  my_df <- inner_join(df_1, df_2, by = "id", suffix = c("x", "y"))

  cat('\nwithout sym and unquote\n')
  qq_show(col_1 != col_2)

  cat('\nwith sym and unquote\n')
  qq_show(!!sym(col_1) != !!sym(col_2))
  cat('\n')

  my_df %>% 
    select(id, col_1, col_2) %>% 
    filter(!!sym(col_1) != !!sym(col_2))
}

### testing: filteron as a string
mydiff("a")
#> 
#> without sym and unquote
#> col_1 != col_2
#> 
#> with sym and unquote
#> ax != ay
#> 
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      id ax    ay   
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1    14 f     k

### testing: filteron as a symbol
mydiff(a)
#> 
#> without sym and unquote
#> col_1 != col_2
#> 
#> with sym and unquote
#> ax != ay
#>  
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      id ax    ay   
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1    14 f     k
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I did not know that I'd have to first `sym` then `!!` for it to work. Good to know that I was almost there!

Comment: @x85ms16: if you use `quo_name` together with `enquo`, you can make the function more flexible as it now works with both string and symbol as input

Answer (score 6):

From https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

> Most dplyr functions use non-standard evaluation (NSE). This is a catch-all term that means they don't follow the usual R rules of evaluation.

This can sometimes create a few issues when attempting to wrap them in functions.
Here is a base version of the function you created.

```
mydiff<- function(filteron, df_1=df1, df_2 = df2){

                 col_1 = paste0(filteron,"x")
                 col_2 = paste0(filteron, "y")

                 my_df <- merge(df1, df2, by="id", suffixes = c("x","y"))

                 my_df[my_df[, col_1] != my_df[, col_2], c("id", col_1, col_2)]  
         }

> mydiff("a")
  id ax ay
3 14  f  k
> mydiff("b")
  id  bx  by
5 18 bar foo
```

This will solve your problem and will likely work as one expects, now and in the future. With less dependencies on outside packages, you reduce these kind of issues and other quirks which may develop in the future as the package authors evolve their work.

Comment: I think the advice about abandoning dplyr needs to be balanced with the downside of doing so, mainly you lose the portability of code to different sources of data.

Comment: Interesting point of view. But perhaps abandoning dplyr expands the portability of ones code as writing functions without it becomes simpler, more predictable, and more consistent. As functions are the building blocks of packages and packages remain the gold standard for shipping ones R code to others, it stands to reason that base code is more portable and reaches a wider range of data sources than dplyr.

Comment: @lionel  How does not using dplyr effect portability of code ?

Comment: I was talking about dplyr backends.

Comment: @Justin This is a great alternative of using just base R to my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems an evaluation issue to me. Try this modified `mydiff` function, using the `lazyeval` package:

```
mydiff <- function(filteron, df_1 = df1, df_2 = df2){
  require(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
  col_1 <- paste0(quo_name(filteron), "x")
  col_2 <- paste0(quo_name(filteron), "y")
  criteria <- lazyeval::interp(~ x != y, .values = list(x = as.name(col_1), y = as.name(col_2)))
  my_df <- inner_join(df_1, df_2, by = "id", suffix = c("x", "y"))
  my_df %>% select(id, col_1, col_2) %>% filter_(criteria)
}
```

You can take a look at the [Functions chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments) from Hadley Wickham’s book **Advanced R** for more on that.

Answer (score 1):

The advice of using base R for simple functions is good, however it does not scale to more complex tidyverse functions and you lose the portability to dplyr backends like databases. If you want to create functions around tidyverse pipelines, you'll have to learn a bit about R expressions and the unquoting operator `!!`. I recommend skimming over the first sections of https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org to get a rough idea of the concepts used here.

Since the function you'd like to create takes a bare column name and does not involve complex expressions (like you would pass to `mutate()` or `summarise()`), we don't need fancy stuff like quosures. We can work with symbols. To create a symbol, use `as.name()` or `rlang::sym()`.

```
as.name("mycolumn")
#> mycolumn

rlang::sym("mycolumn")
#> mycolumn
```

The latter has the advantage of being part of a larger family of functions: `ensym()`, and the plural variants `syms()` and `ensyms()`. We are going to use `ensym()` to capture a column name, i.e. delay the execution of the column in order to pass it to dplyr after a few transformations. Delaying the execution is called "quoting".

I have made a few changes to the interface of your function:

- Take the data frames first for consistency with dplyr functions
- Don't provide defaults for the data frames. These defaults are making too many assumptions.
- Make `by` and `suffix` user-configurable, with reasonable defaults.

Here is the code, with explanations inline:

```
mydiff <- function(df1, df2, var, by = "id", suffix = c(".x", ".y")) {
  stopifnot(is.character(suffix), length(suffix) == 2)

  # Let's start by the easy task, joining the data frames
  df <- dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2, by = by, suffix = suffix)

  # Now onto dealing with the diff variable. `ensym()` takes a column
  # name and delays its execution:
  var <- rlang::ensym(var)

  # A delayed column name is not a string, it's a symbol. So we need
  # to transform it to a string in order to work with paste() etc.
  # `quo_name()` works in this case but is generally only for
  # providing default names.
  #
  # Better use base::as.character() or rlang::as_string() (the latter
  # works a bit better on Windows with foreign UTF-8 characters):
  var_string <- rlang::as_string(var)

  # Now let's add the suffix to the name:
  col1_string <- paste0(var_string, suffix[[1]])
  col2_string <- paste0(var_string, suffix[[2]])

  # dplyr::select() supports column names as strings but it is an
  # exception in the dplyr API. Generally, dplyr functions take bare
  # column names, i.e. symbols. So let's transform the strings back to
  # symbols:
  col1 <- rlang::sym(col1_string)
  col2 <- rlang::sym(col2_string)

  # The delayed column names now need to be inserted back into the
  # dplyr code. This is accomplished by unquoting with the !!
  # operator:
  df %>%
    dplyr::select(id, !!col1, !!col2) %>%
    dplyr::filter(!!col1 != !!col2)
}

mydiff(df1, df2, b)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      id b.x   b.y
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1    18 bar   foo

mydiff(df1, df2, "a")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      id a.x   a.y
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1    14 f     k
```

You can also simplify the function by taking strings instead of bare column names. In this version, I'll use `syms()` to create a list of symbols, and `!!!` to pass it all at once to `select()`:

```
mydiff2 <- function(df1, df2, var, by = "id", suffix = c(".x", ".y")) {
  stopifnot(
    is.character(suffix), length(suffix) == 2,
    is.character(var), length(var) == 1
  )

  # Create a list of symbols from a character vector:
  cols <- rlang::syms(paste0(var, suffix))

  df <- dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2, by = by, suffix = suffix)

  # Unquote the whole list as once with the big bang !!!
  df %>%
    dplyr::select(id, !!!cols) %>%
    dplyr::filter(!!cols[[1]] != !!cols[[2]])
}

mydiff2(df1, df2, "a")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      id a.x   a.y
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1    14 f     k
```

Comment: Great answer! Don't know why you were downvoted. Can we use `quo_name(enquo(var))` to make the function `mydiff2` more flexible i.e. can accept input either as a string or a symbol?

Comment: In this case it would not work because the inputs have to follow the select syntax, since they are forwarded to `select()`. At the same time they can't use select helpers because they are forwarded to `filter()` as well. So the common denominator is just bare column names. That's a good point, I'll add it to the bookdown.

Comment: In that case I'd prefer `mydiff()` to `mydiff2()` cause it's more flexible :)

Comment: @lionel this is super helpful. Thank you for explaining things in detail. Now I can refer back to this when I am writing more complex dplyr functions. Your tips on parameters and quoting are very helpful. One question, Do you need to unquote using `!!` or `!!!` every time you use the column from the parameters?

Comment: Yes, the main pattern for creating functions around dplyr pipelines is "quote-and-unquote". You quote with `enquo()` or `ensym()` (or their plural variants), and you unquote with `!!` and `!!!`.

Answer (score 1):

Finding index for `col_1 != col_2` first might be enough for this problem.

```
mydiff <- function(filteron, df_1 = df1, df_2 = df2){
  require(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
  col_1 <- paste0(quo_name(filteron), "x")
  col_2 <- paste0(quo_name(filteron), "y")
  my_df <-
    inner_join(df_1, df_2, by = "id", suffix = c("x", "y")) %>%
    select(id, col_1, col_2)
  # find indices of different columns
  same <- my_df[, col_1] != my_df[, col_2]
  # return for the rows
  my_df[same, ]
}
my_diff("a")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      id ax    ay   
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1    14 f     k
```