# The user should be able to specify the product (Gold) and time period (yearly or monthly) and the function should automatically take these inputs

Tags: r

```
func_cust<-function(res) {
   res <-
      cust_repay%>%
      group_by(Customer,
               Year=lubridate::year(Month),
               Month=lubridate::month(Month),
               Product) %>%
      summarise(tot_amt = sum(Amount))%>%
      arrange(desc(tot_amt))%>%
      filter(row_number()<= 10)
   print(res)
}

View(func_cust("Gold"))
```

Comment: Here's the shortest relevant intro I could find: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/#a-simpler-interpolation-pattern-with-

Comment: Here's an older question that also asks how to control `dplyr::filter` inside a function, but `dplyr` has been updated since it was asked to make this task less ungainly and complicated. See note above re: "curly curly" operator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560443/create-r-function-using-dplyrfilter-problem/52563183#52563183