# Using filter inside R function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have cost dataset of a device's components by **Year** and by **Quarter-Year**. As some components change price by quarter while others by year. Since I need to calculate the total bill of material of the device by Quarter-Year, I need to standardize all **Year** dataset to be **Quarter-Year**.

Example of Year dataset. The data is in wide format.

```
df <- data.frame(Item = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                 Year2022 = c(2, 3, 8),
                 Year2023 = c(2, 4, 7.8),
                 Year2024 = c(3, 4, 7))
```

Usually this is what I do:

1. define wanted QY
2. convert Year data to long form
3. repeat the year column 4times
4. mutate the QY column by adding numbers at the front (1Q22, 2Q22 etc)
5. filter the dataset to only show the wanted QY

```
#define QY that I wanted
QY_level <-  c("1Q22", "2Q22", "3Q22", "4Q22",
               "1Q23", "2Q23", "3Q23", "4Q23",
               "1Q24")

df_nofunc <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(2:4,
               names_to = "QY",
               values_to = "Values") %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 4L)) %>%
  mutate(QY = paste0(1:4, "Q", str_extract(QY, "[0-9]{2}$"))) %>%
  filter(QY %in% QY_level)
```

That works fine but I have learned that using function is a better way especially since I keep copying and pasting this same code across my project. I want to try to build this into function form but the filter did not work.

I know there are similar questions but I don't quite understand WHY it did not work and only understand that I need to convert the QY column to variable using sym() then unquote it inside filter using !! (bang bang). But it still did not work.

```
generate_QY <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    pivot_longer(2:4,
                 names_to = "QY",
                 values_to = "Values") %>%
    slice(rep(1:n(), each = 4L)) %>%
    mutate(QY = paste0(1:4, "Q", str_extract(QY, "[0-9]{2}$"))) %>% 
    filter(!!sym(QY) %in% QY_level)
  
  return(x)
}


df_withfunc <- generate_QY(df)
```

It still say object 'QY' not found. Why it doesn't work and how do I make it work?

Comment: QY is not defined as one of the variable in the function which is i should be the input argument im trying with your small data set

Comment: You do *not* need to change your `filter()` invocation at all inside the function. [You also don’t need to — and should not — use `return()` here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968)

Comment: so the whole ordeal is because I forgot to assign back to x? not because of filter at all? why is it not a problem like this question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560443/create-r-function-using-dplyrfilter-problem)

Comment: @Helmasan No, you don’t need to assign back to `x` either (and doing so would make no sense). Your original code works *as-is* if you just put it into a function, remove the assignment to `df_nofunc`, and pass `df` as an argument.

Comment: @Helmasan -  the link with the other solution has no return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to change the code at all, beyond removing the assignment. The following works:

```
generate_QY <- function (df) {
  df %>%
    pivot_longer(
      2 : 4,
      names_to = "QY",
      values_to = "Values"
    ) %>%
    slice(rep(seq_len(n()), each = 4L)) %>%
    mutate(QY = paste0(1 : 4, "Q", str_extract(QY, "[0-9]{2}$"))) %>%
    filter(QY %in% QY_level)
}
```

(Note that I *did* change something unrelated, since `1 : x` is error-prone, and `seq_len(x)` should be used instead.)

Comment: Although do note that Konrad - correctly - has removed the quote/unquote from the filter. You only need to mess with `!!sym()` etc. when you are passing in a variable name as a function argument.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comment that you don't need to use return() it's maybe important to notice that in your initial function (`generate_QY`), return would just return the input x because it has not been modified (the output of the x %>% bloc goes nowhere) ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your `filter` slightly within the function:

```
generate_QY <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>%
    pivot_longer(2:4,
                 names_to = "QY",
                 values_to = "Values") %>%
    slice(rep(1:n(), each = 4L)) %>%
    mutate(QY = paste0(1:4, "Q", str_extract(QY, "[0-9]{2}$"))) %>% 
    filter(!!sym("QY") %in% QY_level) # Here! 
  
  return(x)
}

> generate_QY(df)
# A tibble: 27 × 3
   Item  QY    Values
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 A     1Q22       2
 2 A     2Q22       2
 3 A     3Q22       2
 4 A     4Q22       2
 5 A     1Q23       2
 6 A     2Q23       2
 7 A     3Q23       2
 8 A     4Q23       2
 9 A     1Q24       3
10 B     1Q22       3
```

Comment: oh, it works! I'm new to writing function. It seems like I forgot to assign the function back to x? in that case the last call will only return the df as it is?

Comment: No, you don’t need to change `filter()`.